# WooCommerce how to change the order of a single product Attributes - swapping their positions

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I just started using WooCommerce, the default WooCommerce attribute sorting uses alphabetical order.

Is it possible to change `Product -> Attributes` default positions?

**For example** their default positions are alphabetical:

> Brand
> Color
> Size

I would like to change them to:

> Size
> Color
> Brand

Comment: Have you tried https://devanswers.co/change-woocommerce-variations-attributes-custom-sort-order/?

Comment: Hi , i want to change the position(Sorting) of Product Attribute not the attribute of the product (small,large) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible! I would try to `override` the woocommerce template.

Go to the following path:

```
wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > templates > single-product > add-to-cart  

COPY "variable.php" file.
```

Go back to your `active theme` or `active child theme` directory, in the root of your directory create a new folder and call it `woocommerce`, it has to be exactly `woocommerce`.

Then create the same structure as the `woocommerce templates` directory. So your folder structure would be something like this:

```
wp-content > themes > YOUR_ACTIVE_THEME > woocommerce > single-product > add-to-cart

PASTE "variable.php" file.
```

NOW let's override it. Open up "variable.php" and find the following line of code (for me it's on line 38):

```php
foreach ($attributes as $attribute_name => $options) : ?>
```

Once you found it, wrap `$attributes` array into `array_reverse()` php function! So it'd be like this:

```php
foreach (array_reverse($attributes) as $attribute_name => $options) : ?>
```

And the output would be:

> Size
> Color
> Brand

Instead of

> Brand
> Color
> Size